# Spanning the padding of a li element across the width of the ul

Tags: css, html-lists, padding, navbar

I have a dropdown link on a horizontal navigation bar as follows:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The first ul is positioned relatively, and the second ul is positioned absolutely. The second ul has a class, through which I have set a percentage width (about 200% to 250%, I don't remember). However, the li elements within have a rollover background that is as large as the padding set on. What I'm trying to do is to get the padding to span the entire width of the ul, so that when the user rolls over the link, the entire row gets highlighted.

I don't have any example code at this time. Perhaps in several hours I'll edit it in. Hopefully the above is enough to get some ideas rolling.

Comment: can you make a fiddle to point out your problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your example and the text you provided I constructed this: **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FQR6j/)**.

Is this close to what you are after? As you can see, the yellow in the second li highlights the full length:

> so that when the user rolls over the link, the entire row gets highlighted.

If not perhaps you could fill in the details in the jsfiddle and update it to help us out.

Here is the code. The main trick is to set the display to block on hover:

HTML:

```
<ul id='firstUl'>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3
        <ul id='secondUl'>
            <li><a>3</a></li>
            <li><a>4</a></li>
            <li><a>5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
#firstUl
{
   background-color:green; 
   position:relative;
}

#secondUl
{
    width:200%;    
    background-color:blue;
    position:absolute;
}

.li
{
    background-color:red;    
}

#secondUl li
{    
    width:100%
}

#secondUl li:hover a
{
    background-color:yellow;  
    display:block;    
}
```

Comment: Hmm. I haven't tried putting display:block on the hover. I'll give that a shot when I get home and report back.